# Tapped really fast cause skipped click event on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, google-chrome, safari

I am developing an application that needs to detect the touch(or called tap) event precisely and fastly using Vue.

However, I found that for all of my iOS devices, tapping really fast causes missing tap as shown in the gifs that provided below (even wrongly last touch event is triggered for my iPhone 13 mini, no idea why).

CodeSandbox is also provided below and you guys can try it on your own iOS devices.

Anyone have a solution on it? Great Thanks!

CodeSandBox: https://7l45pm.csb.app/

iPhone 13 mini with iOS version 15.1.1
[image]

iPhone 12 Pro with iOS version 14.4
[image]

P.S.

- My android 12 pixel 4a didn’t get this problem
- I tested on both Chrome and Safari browser on my iOS devices, both occuring this problem
- I tried cursor: pointer css, changed to use native button DOM, ways to eliminate 300ms delay on click events in mobile Safari, but no one get luck.